# Integral evaluates to zero when it should not

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I have the following code:

```
f[x_, y_] := KroneckerDelta[x, y]
g[x_, y_] := x*y
r[x_, y_] := Integrate[f[x, t]*g[t, y], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Now I query `r[x,y]`. I expect it be `1/3 KronekerDelta[x,y]`. But Mathematica gives `0`.
On the other hand, `Integrate[r[t, t], {t, 0, 1}]` returns `1/3` as it should be.

So, how can I make `r[x,y]` to be evaluated correctly? I tried the `GenerateConditions` option, but without success.

Comment: Your call `r[x,y]` is as if you typed `Integrate[KroneckerDelta[t, y]*t*y, , {t, 0, 1}]` which is zero as expected. Right?

Comment: @Integrate[KroneckerDelta[t, y]*t*x, {t, 0, 1}]